# How to find the index of a domino in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, indexof

I have a list of lists that include dominos(those are also a list of two integers) and i need to find the index of one of the domino

example:

```
list_of_hand = [[[2, 5], [5, 5], [6, 5], [6, 4]], [[3, 2], [4, 5], [4, 4], [6, 1]]]
```

This list is two lists that includ all the dominos that a player have in is hand.

How can i find the index of the domino `[6, 5]`?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I will need to know which players have the domino [6,5] in is hand. So in this exemple i have two players, so it should return the first one. This will tell me which players will start the game mostly

Comment: `[6, 5] in list_of_hand[0]` to check if it's player 0 and same with 1 for player 1 ? Have you more than 2 players maybe?

Comment: I may have up to 4 players yes this is just an example. I actually need a way to be able to know which player have the [x, y] domino i'm looking for. So in this case if i want to know which one have the [6, 5], it should return me the first player. If I'm looking for the [6,1] it will return the second player, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple function to search through the sublists:

```
x = [[[2, 5], [5, 5], [6, 5], [6, 4]], [[3, 2], [4, 5], [4, 4], [6, 1]]]

def hand_search(L, domino):
    for s in L:
        if domino in s:
            return (L.index(s), s.index(domino))
    return -1

print(hand_search(x, [6,5]))
print(hand_search(x, [6,1]))
```

Output:

```
(0, 2)    # 0 is the player, 2 is the position in their hand
(1, 3)    # 1 is the player, 3 is the position in their hand
```

This would scale to as many players as you want, as long as the nesting is the same.

Comment: In this function the return -1 is only there if the domino is not in L right ?

Comment: Correct, `-1` means the domino is not in any player's hand.

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to use the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html)*(PEP 279)* function in loops like this:

```
def search(l,domino):
    for m,i in enumerate(l):
        for n,j in enumerate(i):
            if domino == j:
                return(m,n)
    return("No match.")

>>> search(list_of_hand,[6,5])
(0, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can keep everything in dictionaries:

```
dominos, hands = {}, {}

def give(d, h):
    hands.setdefault(h, []).append(d)
    dominos.update({d:h})

give( (6,5), 1 )
give( (2,5), 1 )
give( (3,2), 2 )
give( (5,5), 2 )

print hands             # {1: [(6, 5), (2, 5)], 2: [(3, 2), (5, 5)]}
print dominos           # {(2, 5): 1, (3, 2): 2, (6, 5): 1, (5, 5): 2}
print hands[2]          # [(3, 2), (5, 5)]
print dominos[(6,5)]    # 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict with enumerate :

Here is example with two [6,5]

```
list_of_hand = [[[2, 5], [5, 5], [6, 5], [6, 4]], [[3, 2], [4, 5], [4, 4], [6, 1],[6,5]]]

def find_dominos(list_data,value):
    index_v={}
    for i,j in enumerate(list_data):
        for sub,index_sub in enumerate(j):
            if value==index_sub:
                if tuple(value) not in index_v:
                    index_v[tuple(value)]=[(i,sub)]
                else:
                    index_v[tuple(value)].append((i,sub))
    return index_v

print(find_dominos(list_of_hand,[6,5]))
```

output:

```
{(6, 5): [(0, 2), (1, 4)]}
```